# Make a horizontal slider with icon transition

Tags: android

[image]Need help on designing an horizontal slider like the one found in the Stack exchange app [Screenshots attached].
Each element in the slider has an image icon which sticks to the left.
These icons looks like stacked over each other and the transition of images happens when we move across the slider elements.
Can anyone help me achieving this design in native development.